# HttpURLConnection times out on some devices with targetSdkVersion 29

Tags: android, http, timeout, httpurlconnection

I updated my app that uses HttpURLConnection to read data from a web service from targetSdkVersion 21 to 29. Most devices work just like they did before, but sum customers report problems.
I implemented some test functions to get more information about what's wrong. Surprisingly, the connection times out and throws a SocketTimeoutException.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Simplified usage of HttpURLConnection:

```
...
try
{
    URL url = new URL( uri );
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
    con.setConnectTimeout( 30000 );
    con.setReadTimeout( 60000 );
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if( responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK )
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
catch( SocketTimeoutException e )
{
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: First, why are you using basic HTTP URL Connection? There are many much better HTTP clients now. OkHttp is one of the best. There might be some new things you need to implement manually on newer devices, while a library like OkHttp might have already implemented them

Comment: Which Android version on those devices?

Comment: `to get more information about what's wrong. Surprisingly, the connection times out and throws a SocketTimeoutException.` I wonder that you did not have that before to inform the users. Then the users could have told you already.

Comment: Dead network or poor internet connection could be the reason behind the SocketTimeouts! Just cross check the nature of the internet of the connection used by the customers who are facing the issue.

Comment: @AhmadSattout, I also tried OkHttp and have the same issue that it can't connect to the server.

Comment: @blackapps, Android 10. It's all on Samsung devices, but others don't have the same problems (e.g. a customer has a Samsung S10e, but there are more than 50 other with the same device which don't report this issue). A customer says that he can ping the url in another app. The URL is set in the res\xml\network_security_config.xml

Comment: `.. some devices with targetSdkVersion 29` Devices have no targetSdkVersion. Your app has. A device has just a sdk version. Pleease update your post to tell whats going on.

Comment: `The URL is set in the res\xml\network_security_config.xml` Why? Why would you? Take it out.